# If the deployment has 2 replicas, will the scheduler in quarkus be executed 2 times?

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus

am new to kubernetes. i have question about kubernetes.
i have quarkus deployment and have scheduling periodic tasks.
is there any chance that the scheduler will run as many replicas?

```
    @Scheduled(cron="3 0 2 * * ?")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quarkus scheduler in multiple pods (other than concurrentExecution = SKIP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076151/quarkus-scheduler-in-multiple-pods-other-than-concurrentexecution-skip)

Comment: what you also can do is (if possible), deploy a cronjob into K8s and let that cronjob make a REST call to your service to execute the task. 

Check these links: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/
https://florianbuchner.com/kubernetes-curl-cronjob-for-internal-service/

Comment: i just trying change my quarkus version , 
[link](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14924)
thankyou guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Unless you implement some kind of clustering in between your applications, replicas are standalone processes that would execute just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to schedule a single task execution per cluster you will need to use a clustered quartz setup: https://quarkus.io/guides/quartz